# nvidia quadro K1100M issue with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a Dell M3800 with nvidia QUADRO K1100M and intel HD4600 running Ubuntu 14.04.
I have installed the nvidia driver using this steps:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install nividia-common nvidia-331
```

Unfortunately this will install the driver but the graphic card won't be recognized.

[image]

The nvidia x-server doesn't show all the option.Also if I select the nvidia graphic card as default the system will freeze either right after the log in or before (showing just the cursor).
[image]

I've tried to clean up everything using

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

and re install other drivers but nothing.

I have tried this one as well with no success http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

I really need to use my graphic card, any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following [document](http://xmodulo.com/install-configure-nvidia-optimus-driver-ubuntu.html) to configure a M3800 + QUADRO K1100M + Intel HD4600 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and everything works correctly and I can switch (manually) from Nvidia to Intel and vice versa. Do not forget to uninstall Bumblebee if you did so.

Comment: How is you performance using the nvidai card? For me it's horrible, I get 220 in glmark2

Comment: 2890 in high performance mode and  2829 in high quality mode.

Comment: So just a plain install, then use the additional drivers program to choose the 331 version? Then all good?

Comment: Yes. To get the nvidia software you have to add the following repository:sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa. I use the version 346. By the way, using the Nvidia card on battery is almost not feasible. The battery is very quickly empty! :-(

Comment: Yeah I want to use the nvidia only when at my desk, mostly 90% of the time, and then switch to intel for when on the go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, unfortunately I can't still switch between graphic cards, the nvidia simply doesn't work. Might need to use a clean Ubuntu install.

Comment: What hardware do you have ?

Comment: @kilop I have the same laptop and probably the same nvidia card and I have the same issue.  When I have nvidia enabled, it's black screen.  No login no nothing.  To switch card from the command line you can use prime-select intel/nvidia.  I'm running it in intel mode right now and it works okay-ish.  Though if I run any app that needs GLX support it crashes.

Comment: On a side note.  I tried nvidia-331, nvidia-346, and nvidia-352 (currently installed) and they all have the exact same issue.  I have a feeling it's an some obscure flag that I'm missing.  Maybe the 4K display is confusing it somehow.

Comment: Guys, I use a M3800 but NOT a 4K display. As  I knew beforehand from my investigations that neither Linux nor Windows (that I don't want to use) didn't scale the 4K screens very smoothly(correctly),  I have bought a full hd M3800. That could explain your problems...

Comment: @csgeek same issue. I know how to switch between cards but I can only use intel now which is very annoying. Can't run the Quadro. Can't believe nobody knows how to solve this .

Comment: @RudyVissers hello, Windows now scales properly, Ubuntu too. The only problem is the usage of the graphic card. Have you checked if you are running Ubuntu using the nvidia or intel?